# Table can't be updated for my case

Tags: sql, oracle

I created simple table

```
create table test(
 name char(8),
 name2 varchar2(8)
);
```

... and I insert a value in the table ...

```
insert into test values('ABC',NULL);
```

At this point, I tried updating the value I inserted ...

```
update test
set name2 = 'ABC'
where name = 'ABC';
```

... but my query doesn't work as I intend. It says: 0 rows updated.

Why it doesn't make that update?

Comment: Did you commit the original insert? Is the update in the same session as the insert?

Comment: @kevinsky, nice spot, @user3881015 is there any specific reason you are using `CHAR` and not `VARCHAR2` for your first column?

Comment: Name can't hold `'ABC'` because it is a `CHAR(8)`, or a string of 8 characters. When you insert `'ABC'` Oracle stores `'ABC     '`, and `'ABC     ' <> 'ABC'` so the update does not update.

Answer (score 2):

Try it all in a single script run in one go (and use `VARCHAR2` for both columns unless you really need to use `CHAR`):

```
create table test(name varchar2(8) name2 varchar2(8))
/

insert into test values('ABC', NULL)
/

update test set name2 = 'ABC' where name = 'ABC'
/
```

If that returns output similar to:

```
Table created
1 row inserted
1 row updated
```

Then it was a session issue.

Table creation is DDL but the insert and subsequent update are DML and will need to be committed to be "seen" by other sessions in your database. i.e.:

```
create table test(name varchar2(8) name2 varchar2(8))
/

insert into test values('ABC', NULL)
/

commit
/
```

Then in another session you could issue:

```
update test set name2 = 'ABC' where name = 'ABC'
/

commit
/
```

Hope it helps